# Image size for the iPhone - Portrait vs Landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uiimageview

I have images of size 320 x 480.  I left a blank space at the bottom of these images to account for the tab bar at the bottom of the iPhone screen.

The 320 x 480 looks good on the iphone in portrait mode but it looks stretched on landscape mode.

These images are loaded programmatically.

What can I do to not having them look stretched and perhaps how to use a higher resolution.

My understanding is that a higher resolution means the image will be too big for the iPhone screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using `UIImageView`. By default the `contentMode` property of any `imageView` is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` that means it will fill the entire view thereby stretching the image.

change this to - `[imgView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit]`, what this does is to respect the aspect ratio of the image.

more [here in apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewContentModeScaleToFill)

Answer (score 0):

The screen Size of iPhone and iPad are given below. Based on the mode you can create image size.

iPhone:

Portrait : 320x460
  Landscape : 480x300

iPad:
  portrait : 768x1004
  Landscape : 1024x748